# how does windows command prompt handle consecutive CTRL + C (SIGINT) signals?

Tags: c, windows, signals

I am running a program from the windows command prompt, and I am getting some weird behavior when I press CTRL C, resume, then CTRL C again.

ctrl C causes the program I am using (icarus verilog) to pause the first time I hit ctrl C. I then type "cont"(an icarus verilog command to continue after being paused) and then it exits that handler and reenters the main loop (I have print statements inside that let me know) it was in the 1st time.

However, the 2nd press of CTRL + C does not hit the SIGINT handler.

I am wondering whether windows interprets a 2nd ctrl C event differently and in fact sends a different signal to the program, or perhaps sends a terminate signal.

I was going to post the main code loop, but i realize I can simplify things for the reader.

this function here:

```
extern "C" void signals_handler(int)
{
    printf("Inside Signals handler \n");
      schedule_stopped_flag = true;
}
```

is hit by CTRL C the first time, but not the 2nd time it is called.

It is attached by passing this function pointer in the function:

```
static void signals_capture(void)
{
      signal(SIGINT, &signals_handler);
}
```

the documentation of the function "signal" can be seen here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/csignal/signal/

There does not appear to be any place within the code where the signal handler is detached.

Comment: Or maybe the program is handling the signal only once because of some bug?

Comment: that's the thing. i am looking at the program as it runs. I don't see any issue at all. the code looks fine, and stepping through it it looks like the code is running fine, it just doesn't receive the second signal even though it's in the right loop. I'm wondering if it's due to some difference between windows and linux.

Comment: I guess my only option to try next is to figure out how to use gdb to capture the signal and then see where it goes. However, when i tried that a few minutes ago I was confused as to why the program was exiting. However,based on this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

it seems that i need to handle the exception that is raised

Comment: hmm anyway i think your comments helped get me on the right track. my guess is that somewhere some call is deattaching the signals handler too early. I don't see where it is, but that must be the case

Comment: And that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @JamesJoshuaStreet If you think that is a possibility, you can use `sigaction` to examine whether the handler is still installed.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have to reattach the handler after it is activated. I am guessing the operating system is removing it or something, but it wasn't the code I was looking at that deattached it. However, doing as the site below recommends and reatttaching the handler seems to work.

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-that-doesnt-terminate-when-ctrlc-is-pressed/

One slightly bothersome thing is that the documentation:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/signal

states that
"
If the signal handler is called NOT as a result of abort or raise (in other words, the signal handler is asynchronous), the behavior is undefined if
the signal handler calls any function within the standard library, except
abort
_Exit
quick_exit
signal with the first argument not being the number of the signal currently handled.
"

I take this to mean that since I am calling the signal with first argument being the same number of the currently handled signal, that I should expect undefined behavior. This is slightly bothersome, which makes me wonder if there are any other options. However, for now this seems to work.

Comment: If you are using a modern version of Visual Studio, there should be no problem with calling runtime functions from the control-C signal handler.  However, if it worries you, you do have the option of using the native API rather than the C library.

Comment: FYI, Windows doesn't implement POSIX signals, so this isn't the operating system. Console applications register handlers that get called by `kernel32!CtrlRoutine` on a thread that's started remotely by csrss.exe, after it gets a control event message from conhost.exe. Microsoft's C runtime, if used at all, registers a handler to implement `SIGINT` and `SIGBREAK` signals, but you can't send `SIGINT` to an arbitrary console process. You can maybe trigger a `CTRL_C_EVENT` in a process group (or all processes) if you're attached to the same console and Ctrl+C isn't disabled.